# Spectrums (Fourier transform) in a changing space

Tags: geometry, fourier-transform, tensors

Imagine a simple wave in a [euclidean] space. You can measure its wavelength. If you have a complex wave you can split (Fourier transform) it into simple waves.

But what if the shape of the wave affects the [euclidean] space?

How to analyze such waves then?

It would mean that every wave corresponds to a spectrum of its own, but we always can see only one wave from that spectrum...

Comment: What do you mean by "the wave affects the Euclidean space?" Are you looking for a $n$-dimensional Fourier transform? https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fourier_transform#Fourier_transform_on_Euclidean_space

Comment: @Manlio I mean stretching of the space and changing lengths, like in theory of Relativity. "N-dimensional" doesn't sound like it, but maybe I don't know something. It's not it if it's just talking about higher dimensions... (thank you for answering!)

Comment: Your question is vague. Try to be more specific about *how* a "wave" can affect a "space".

Comment: @user619894 I apologize! If only something like this already existed I wouldn't need to be precise! At the moment I only can offer an analogy to theory of Relativity (where mass can curve spacetime, for example), but I understand that it's probably of no use... no sense to ask probably if generalization doesn't already exist

Comment: Can you explain the analogy to relativity? Do you mean General Relativity or Special Relativity?

Comment: @user619894 The General Relativity I think. But if an analogy is OK I may come up with a simpler and more on-topic one I guess (and make a picture), but I have to go now... will do it later

Imagine a frequency domain A with a function (a)(wave) and another "overlayed" frequency domain B (initially they are identical); as you change the function (a) domain B gets stretched or transformed in some ways (so for every different shape of function (a) you have a "different" domain B) 

Maybe the domain B defines what frequencies give what color and so stretches change what defines a color

Comment: @user619894 I guess I won't make a picture, nobody needs this, I better come up later with something better... also I found out about microlocal analysis https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microlocal_analysis